# Because testing_app requires SDK version >=2.16.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, build-runner

I am learning more about testing and i want to use [Mockito Package](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and [Build Runner Packate](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) then i have my class Cat inside lib/models/cat.dart

[image: My cat class]

then i have my lib/test/cat_test.dart file to test cat class

[image: cat_test.dart file]

this is my pubspec.yaml (part of it)

[image: Pubspec.yaml]

The problem is thrown when i want to run the next command :

> dart run build_runner build

and the problem is the next:

> Resolving dependencies in /Users/adm/Documents/Things of david/PRACTICAS/Flutter/testing_app...
> The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1.
> Because testing_app requires SDK version >=2.16.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

Flutter doctor:

[image: Flutter doctor]

thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"` change in your pubsec.yaml

Comment: The problem continue but with different error: 
Resolving dependencies in /Users/adm/Documents/Things of david/PRACTICAS/Flutter/testing_app... (1.7s)
Because testing_app depends on integration_test from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving
  failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter pub get` instead of `dart pub get`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the error message:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1. Because testing_app requires SDK version >=2.16.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

It means that the project needs Dart SDK in version 2.16.1 (at least), and your version is 2.15.1.

You should upgrade your Flutter version with `flutter upgrade`. For more info see [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by changing the environment sdk version.

Open the project pubspec yaml file and next to environment: sdk:, change the version number to the minimum version required by the package or app as instructed in the error message.

I had to downgrade my sdk version from from ">=2.17.0-182.0.dev <3.0.0" to ">=2.16.0-182.0.dev <3.0.0".

[image: Screenshot showing pubspec yaml file]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your flutter by running

```
flutter upgrade
```

This is going to take some time. After upgrade is done you can run

```
flutter pub get
```